# Using Vistaswitcher Exclusions with Bloomberg

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

I love Vistaswitcher but I can't seem to get the exclusion feature to work with my Bloomberg.

The way the Bloomberg works, there are maybe 10 different function windows that open automatically, and when I use Vistaswitcher I have to wade through them every time.

Most of them are static windows that I wouldn't ever want to switch to;  static feeds essentially, but I can't seem to exclude these, either by process, window class, or window title. No matter how I set up the exclusions they keep appearing in the switcher.

Anyway to configure this better?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was a silly question I guess. I couldn't get the exclusions to work but I found a workaround. I simply put all the pages I wanted onto one monitor and set vistaswitcher to only shuffle through apps open on that monitor. Worked like a charm. Very easy to do. Just go to preferences and then adjust the settings under the behavior tab.